# Vol specifications under Heath Jarrow Morton framework

Tags: interest-rates, modeling, heath-jarrow-morton

What are some of the common forward vol specifications under HJM framework used in the industry. I guess most common would be 2 and 3 factor models, but any pointers to more details would be very useful. An example would be -  parametric instantaneous forward rate vol as sum of two exponential decaying vols (same as G2++ model).

PS: could you please also point to any references on the model calibration as well.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have a reference for such specification?

Comment: [Here](https://www.itwm.fraunhofer.de/fileadmin/ITWM-Media/Zentral/Pdf/Berichte_ITWM/2009/bericht_170.pdf) is the link to G2++ model I mentioned as an example. There seem to be lot of different ways to specify the vol, I am keen to know which ones are popular in the industry.

Comment: I used HJM within the industry for a long time.  The vol specification I used became more refined over time and was quite complex (multi parameter).  I'm sure we never published it, since it is a competitive advantage.

Comment: @dm63 I totally see that people might not want to share precise details. Could you please point to any publicly available literature that could help cover some ground.